# Angular2 How to trigger (click) event without clicking

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, mouseclick-event

I want to pass data from HTML to the component so I've created an event like this:

```
<div id="tutor-price" (click)="passCharge(r.value['charge'])"><span id="month">월 8회</span> <span id="price"> {{r.value['charge']}} </span></div>
```

**And in component:**

```
passCharge(charge){
   this.charge = charge;
   console.log(this.charge,"give me the number")
}
```

If I click the event, I see everything's working fine. 
But I want to trigger this click event automatically since I want the component to use 'this.charge' value right away once the component is done the loading.

Is there any way I can trigger (click) event automatically?

Comment: Call the method?

Comment: You can call the method on ngOnInit() { }  , it will be called once the page is loaded.

Comment: I can't just call the method passCharge(r.value['charge']); in ngOnInit()


casue component can't read r.value['charge'] it won't compile

If I add otheriwse, it doens't print what I want

Comment: What is `r` in your code?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Give it a ViewChild reference :

```
<div #myDiv id="tutor-price" (click)="passCharge(r.value['charge'])"><span id="month">월 8회</span> <span id="price"> {{r.value['charge']}} </span></div>
```

In your component :

```
@ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

triggerFalseClick() {
    let el: HTMLElement = this.myDiv.nativeElement;
    el.click();
}
```

Comment: What is HTMLElement? I tried this but it's printing error

./MainComponent class MainComponent - inline template:57:8 caused by: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: HTMLElement is an HTML element, what is usually returned by `document.getElementById()` in native JS. This error occurs because you didn't declare the elementRef.

Comment: By declare u meant this?
1.import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

2. constructor(
    el:ElementRef) {

  }

I tried both still the same error :(

Comment: Don't put it in the contructor, put it as a local variable.

Comment: Also, where do you call the fakeClick function ?

Comment: i call the fakeClick function from ngOnInit

Comment: implement AfterViewInit and call it in it then (OnInit hasn't loaded the view yet)

Comment: But if you want to test if it works, simply add a timeout !

Comment: ERROR TypeError: el.click is not a function in chrome. I get the valid HTMLElement.

Comment: If you have the `HTMLElement` and can't trigger a `click`, then please provide a [mcve] and make a question on SOF.

Comment: @trichetriche why not just "this.myDiv.nativeElement.click();"

Comment: @Xan because I explain, instead of giving the quickest solution.

Comment: this.myDiv.nativeElement; is undefined ??
doesn't work even after use after AfterViewInit in angular 7

Comment: @ViewChild('myDiv', {static: true}) myDiv: ElementRef;

Answer (score 11):

You can trigger click event in ngOnInit() like this: 
`

```
<div #divClick id="tutor-price" (click)="passCharge(r.value['charge'])">
    <span id="month">월 8회</span> 
    <span id="price"> {{r.value['charge']}} </span>
</div>`
```

In component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  //component decoraters
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('divClick') divClick: ElementRef;
  ngOnInit() {
      // your other code
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.divClick.nativeElement.click();
    }, 200);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45027961/2334352), if you get the error "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined" or even "Cannot read property click of undefined", as OP clearly states in the comments to answer provided, use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45921878/2334352):

> If you want to get a reference of an element that hosts a component or directive you need to specify that you want the element instead of the component or directive

```
@ViewChild('myDiv', { read: ElementRef }) myDiv: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just landed here from a research and I resolved to make my contribution to the topic. :)

You can create and dispatch an event too:

```
const domEl: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div'); 
// or do whatever you have to do to get the DOM Element

function triggerEvent(el: HTMLElement, evt: Event): void {
    if (el && evt) {
        const fakeEvent = new Event(evt, {bubbles: false, cancelable: false});

        el.dispatchEvent(fakeEvent);
    }
}

// adding some events to make this example more functional, 
// but do what you have to do to bind an event to your DOM Element

domEl.addEventListener('click', (ev) => { console.log('click', ev); });
domEl.addEventListener('focus', (ev) => { console.log('focus', ev); });
domEl.addEventListener('blur', (ev) => { console.log('blur', ev); });


triggerEvent(domEl, 'click'); // to dispatch click event
triggerEvent(domEl, 'focus'); // to dispatch focus event
triggerEvent(domEl, 'blur'); // to dispatch blur event
```

Hope that it helps you or someone else in the futures researches. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<div #tutor id="tutor-price" (click)="passCharge(tutor.value['charge'])"><span id="month">월 8회</span> <span id="price"> {{tutor.value['charge']}} </span></div>
```

Hope so this can help you ..

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
tutor:any;
@Component({
      //your component decorater tags
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
   ngOnInit(){
      this.charge = this.tutor.value['charge'];
   }
   passCharge(charge){
   this.charge = charge;

}
```

Comment: How would this even compile?  passCharge(charge) and this.charge = charge is being done inside the class itself and not in any method?