# Angular: nativeElement is undefined on ViewChild

Tags: angular

I want to access the DOM of a component using `ViewChild`. But when I try to access the `nativeElement` property, it's `undefined`.

Below is the snippet.

```ts
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertComponent } from './alert.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
    <app-alert #alert>My alert</app-alert>
      <button (click)="showAlert()">Show Alert</button>`
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('alert') alert;

  showAlert() {
    console.log('alert (showalert)', this.alert.nativeElement);
    this.alert.show();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('alert (afterviewinit)', this.alert.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

Please take a look at the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Fuo6ePAidWyZyFwcaif?p=preview).

Answer (score 159, accepted):

If you want to get a reference of an element that hosts a component or directive you need to specify that you want the element instead of the component or directive

```ts
@ViewChild('alert', { read: ElementRef }) alert:ElementRef;
```

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)

In your case I guess you need two different `@ViewChild()` one for the component reference to be able to access the `show()` method, and a 2nd one to be able to access DOM attributes.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/6GRc3oYOtaRod1d0ZCUB?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! By default it returns the component instance. How can I explicitly specify the `read` property to return the component instance? Also, it would be great if you can tell what are the other values I can set for different purposes.

Comment: If it's a plain HTML element, the default is `ElementRef`, it it hosts a component or directive, you'll get the component instance by default. You can just use the type name of the component or directive to request a specific one like `@ViewChild('alert', { read: AlertComponent }) alert: AlertComponent;`

Comment: Works for `ViewChildren` too

Comment: In angular 8, you have to set the static option (which is now mandatory) to false. `@ViewChild('alert', { read: ElementRef, static:false })` Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: Actually `{static: false}` is the default. It's the `{read: ElementRef}` that is now required to get it working. Seems like a massively breaking change to have no mention of it whatsoever in the documentation.

Comment: @Neutrino static has changed in v9 as far as I remember, but read is quite old v3 or v4 I guess. You need `read` if you do not want the default type. For example if it's an Angular component, you'll get the component instead of the ElementRef by default.

Comment: How do I get both the `ElementRef` and the `AlertComponent` at once? In my case I have many of them so I'm using `ViewChildren` instead, and with this answer I'd have to call `ViewChildren` twice, but I don't want to assume that the order they get is perfectly synchronized all the time.

Comment: Figured it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58453475/4135063

Comment: @PedroA Did you resolved `ViewChildren` looking for same use case.

Comment: @sankarmuniyappa What I did is what I found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58453475/4135063