# Remove or add class in Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have a list and the plugin (`dragula`) I used, adds certain CSS class on certain action. I am using Angular 5. I want to find out the presence of certain class (`myClass`) and remove that and replace with (`yourClass`). In jQuery we can do that like this

```js
$( "p" ).removeClass( "myClass" ).addClass( "yourClass" );
```

How can I achieve this in Angular5. Here the main issue is that `myClass` is added automatically to the selected `li` by the plugin. So using a function I cant set the class.

When I tried with renderer2, it is removing the CSS class and adding another class. But it is adding only to the first `li`. My code is:

```js
let myTag ; 
myTag = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector("li");
this.renderer.addClass(myTag, 'gu-mirrorss')
this.renderer.removeClass(myTag, 'dragbox');
```

```html
<div  class="right-height" id ='dest' [dragula]='"second-bag"' [dragulaModel]="questions"> 
       {{ questions.length == 0 ? ' Drag and drop questions here ' : ' '}}
       <li #vc  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title= {{question.questionSentence}} class="well dragbox"  *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index" [attr.data-id]="question.questionId" [attr.data-index]="i" (click)="addThisQuestionToArray(question,i, $event)" [class.active]="isQuestionSelected(question)"  #myId > {{question.questionId}} {{question.questionSentence}}</li>
</div>
```

Comment: In "Angular way" you use [ngClass]="{'class1':condition1,'class2':condition2}"

Comment: Do you want to add/remove from typescript?

Comment: @SandipPatel yes.  I think  [ngClass]="'class1':condition1,'class2':condition2}" is not possible because the list  will chnage dynamically and the class is added by the plugin I want it to remove on perticular condition

Comment: [ngClass] will not work in this situation, since the plugin adds the class. You need to use ElementRef to find it and remove it manually.

Comment: Don't imperatively set the class. Set it in the template and activate/deactivate it conditionally (in the template) based on a public boolean variable of your ts file (or some boolean expression). e.g. `<div ...[class.my-css-class]="myClassBooleanVariable" [class.your-css-class]="yourClassBooleanVariable"...>`

Answer (score 39):

Import  `ElementRef` from angular core and define in constructor then try below code:

Below line of code will give you first occurrence of `<p>` tag from Component.  `querySelector` gives you first item and `querySelectorAll` gives you all items from DOM.

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
}

let myTag = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector("p"); // you can select html element by getelementsByClassName also, please use as per your requirement.
```

Add Class:

```
if(!myTag.classList.contains('myClass'))
{
    myTag.classList.add('myClass'); 
}
```

Remove Class:

```
myTag.classList.remove('myClass');
```

Comment: using ElemntRef it is working but angular documentation says using ElementRef  may cause xss attack `https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef`

Comment: this is the way to achieve your requirement

Comment: yes of course is it possible to do with any secure way

Comment: I think it will possible with Renderer2 `https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2`. I didnt tested

Answer (score 20):

You can use id in your html

```
<button #namebutton class="btn btn-primary">login</button>
```

add viewchild in your.ts

```
@ViewChild('namebutton', { read: ElementRef, static:false }) namebutton: ElementRef;
```

create a function that will trigger the event

```
 actionButton() {
    this.namebutton.nativeElement.classList.add('class-to-add')
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.namebutton.nativeElement.classList.remove('class-to-remove')
    }, 1000);
  }
```

and call the function.

If your native element is undefined check this answer
[Angular: nativeElement is undefined on ViewChild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921819/angular-nativeelement-is-undefined-on-viewchild)

Answer (score 5):

Here are multiple ways to pass classes

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

From [Official Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change all li.myClass, you can do like this:

Note the `#questions` in the container div.

#### Component.ts

```
@ViewChild('questions') questions: any;

questions.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.myClass').forEach(
  question => {
    question.classList.remove('myClass');
    question.classList.add('newClass');
  }
)
```

#### Component.html

```
<div #questions class="right-height" id ='dest' [dragula]='"second-bag"' [dragulaModel]="questions"> 
       {{ questions.length == 0 ? ' Drag and drop questions here ' : ' '}}
       <li
         #vc 
         data-toggle="tooltip"
         data-placement="bottom"
         title= {{question.questionSentence}}
         class="well dragbox"
         *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index"
         [attr.data-id]="question.questionId"
         [attr.data-index]="i"
         (click)="addThisQuestionToArray(question,i, $event)"
         [class.active]="isQuestionSelected(question)"
         #myId>
           {{question.questionId}} {{question.questionSentence}}
      </li>
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting   TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined. Because using `this.questions.nativeElement.querySelectorAll` because  I use this inside a function

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand correctly, is it working now?

Answer (score 1):

**The Best and easiest way is : -**

If student is null then dissabled else not. Use this in button attribute. If you are using bootstrap theme

```
[ngClass]="{disabled: (students === null) ? true : false}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If 'yourFlag' is true, 'classB' is enabled.

This worked in angular10.

```
class="classA {{yourFlag ? 'classB' : ''}}"
```