# Are there any ways to get ElementRef and Component ref in ViewChildren?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I want to get a list of native elements and related components to them from view.

I'll try to do something like that, but it doesn't work:

```
@ViewChildren('element', { read: [ElementRef, MyComponent] }) private elements: QueryList<any>; // <-- not work

or

@ViewChildren('element', { read: MyComponent }) private elements: QueryList<MyComponent>;
...
this.elements.first.nativeElement // <-- undefined
```

This works, but it doesn't look right:

```
@ViewChildren('element', { read: ElementRef }) private elements: QueryList<ElementRef>;
@ViewChildren('element', { read: MyComponent}) private components: QueryList<MyComponent>;
```

My template short example:

```
<virtual-scroller #scroll>
  <my-component #element *ngFor="let c of components"></my-component>
</virtual-scroller>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way to do this is to inject:

```
@ViewChildren('element', { read: MyComponent}) private components: QueryList<MyComponent>;
```

in parent component and expose `elementRef` from child:

```
class MyComponent {
    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {}
}
```

and then just access `elementRef` directly:

```
this.components.forEach(component => component.elementRef);
```

Answer (score 6):

One way to solve it is to **inject** in each **component** the **ElementRef** as a public property and then, by iterating over the components(resulted from `ViewChildren`), you can access everything you want.

#### my-component.component.ts

```js
@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class MyComponent {
 /* ... */

 constructor (public elementRef: ElementRef) { }

 /* ... */
}
```

#### parent.component.html

```html
<virtual-scroller #scroll>
  <my-component #element *ngFor="let c of components"></my-component>
</virtual-scroller>
```

#### parent.component.ts

```js
@ViewChildren('element', { read: MyComponent }) private components: QueryList<MyComponent>

/* ... */

ngAfterViewChecked () {
 this.components.forEach(c => console.log(c.elementRef))
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use ContentChildren instead of ViewChildren

```
@ContentChildren(YourComponent) components: QueryList<YourComponent>;
```

I have made an example in stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfjh6e

Comment: This is not good answer for @I.Bond question. There is a difference for use ContentChildren and ViewChildren. I.Bond doesn't use ng-content, so in this case ViewChildren has to be used for access to its children