# How to get mat tab width?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I am trying to get the width of the tab.

And I expect to get like `nativeElement.clientWidth`

If I use ViewChild like:

```
@ViewChild('matTab', {static: false}) matTab: ElementRef;
    
<mat-tab label="Overview" #matTab>Overview</mat-tab>
```

But I try to read `matTab` by console.log(this.matTab)

It shows:

[image: Screenshot]

I can't find `nativeElement`.

Do I have to use `document.getElementByID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the width of tab by using `mat-tab` element because `<mat-tab>` is not showing in DOM. You can use *Chrome DevTools* and see they are using only `<mat-tab-header>` and `<mat-tab-content>` inside the `mat-tab-group`.

You should get the width of tab-group instead of only single tab:

```
<mat-tab-group #matTab>
    <mat-tab label="Overview">Overview</mat-tab>
    ...
</mat-tab-group>
```

You also need to add `read: ElementRef`:

> If you want to get a reference of an element that hosts a component or directive you need to specify that you want the element instead of the component or directive
>
> -- [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45921878)

```
@ViewChild('matTab', { read: ElementRef, static:false }) matTab: ElementRef;
```

Now the new `mat-tab` have `nativeElement` attribute.