# JQuery Trigger equivalent in Angular2 or higher

Tags: angular, keypress

Hi all As I was aware of trigger() method in JQuery for triggering the event manually, I want to know that is there any equivalent method in Angular2 or higher. Recently I have a textarea in which a text variable is bind from the typescript now whenever the variable's value changes from typescript I want to fire keypress event of textarea.

Here are my code

```
 <textarea  rows="3" id='myInputText'  class="form-control textareaPage" 
  name="businessQuery" [(ngModel)]="text" #textarea (input)="addTags(); getContectualHelp()" #queryEditor="ngModel" taxonomyValidate ngModel required [attr.arrayIncludes]="listOfTaxonomy" placeholder="Please type query to search" style="border-radius: 0; min-height:70px;"> </textarea>
```

And the method which loads text in textarea is as follows

```
 loadQuery(event) {
 this.text = event.target.innerText;
 }
```

I want to manually trigger keypress event while loading text into textarea by 
this method loadQuery(event).

Comment: what you need to do with that keypress?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 How to trigger (click) event without clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027331/angular2-how-to-trigger-click-event-without-clicking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ViewChild with a template variable to get a reference to the textarea, then use the Renderer to invoke dispatchEvent to fire the event:

```
 @ViewChild('textarea') textarea:ElementRef;

loadQuery() {
 let event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
 this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.textarea.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event]);
 }
```