# How to Programmatically Trigger 'Click' Event in Angular 6?

Tags: events, onclick, angular6

Essentially, I want to trigger the input button in the page using TypeScript

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027331/angular2-how-to-trigger-click-event-without-clicking/45027961

Comment: yes, this what im looking for thnx

Answer (score 8):

//its no different than doing it in vanilla JS

```
let elem = document.getElementById('submitBtn');

let evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window
    });

elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: I am getting error -ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null

Answer (score 4):

Use @ViewChild as follows in .ts

```
 @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;

 let inputElement: HTMLElement = this.fileInput.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
 inputElement.click();
```

In your .html,

```
 <input #fileInput type="file" ng2FileSelect (onFileSelected)="fileUpload($event)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

JS code:

```
document.getElementById('mat-checkbox-1-input').click();
```

**Happy Coding!!!**